# Could not establish FTP connection, invalid host or port in magento 2.2.5

Tags: error, magento-2.2.5, ftp

i include the use `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp;` at the top nd connct the ftp as

```
 $connection = $this->ftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => '00.000.00.000',
                        'user' => 'admin',
                        'password' => 'test@123',
                        'passive' => true,
                        'Port'=>21

                    )
                );
```

this code is work fine in my local environment..
But when am trying with the same code in digitalocean (SFTP) THROWS AN ERROR like

> Could not establish FTP connection, invalid host or port.

please help me

Comment: check from digitalocean, the ip might be blocked by digitalocean firewall

Comment: Did you ever find why ? I have currently the same pb (not with digital ocean), and the ftp_connect works on an external script, on the same server...